# How to return true/false from a function in php

Tags: php

How can I use the return true/false for another function?

```
<?php    
 class Bet {    
     private $Client;
     private $Secret;
     private $Server;    
     public function __construct() {
         $this->Client = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
         $this->Secret = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
         $this->Server = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
     }    
     public function Bet($Type, $Chance) {    
         if($Type == 'auto') {    
                 $hash  = hash('sha512', $this->Client . $this->Secret . $this->Server);
                 $Result = round(hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)) / 42949672.95, 2);

                     if($Result < $Chance) {
                         return true;
                     } else {
                         return false;                      
                     }
         }
     }
 }
```

?>

Heres what I been trying:

```
if(isset($_POST['chance'], $_POST['bet'])) {
    print_r($Bet->Bet('auto', $_POST['chance']));

    if($Bet == true)
    {
        return "1";
    } else {
        return "2";
        }    
    }
```

But I can't see to get inside the if state.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($Bet)
{
    return "1";
} else {
    return "2";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate your class:

```
$bet = new Bet($type, $chance);
```

but a constructor cannot return a value like you are doing.

try something like this:

```
public function betTest() { return what you want; }

[...]

if ($bet->betTest()) { return 1; } else { return 2; }
```

or use a static method:

```
public static function betTest() { /.../ }

if (Bet::betTest()) { ... }
```

Based on your code:

```
<?php    
 class Bet {    
     private $Client;
     private $Secret;
     private $Server;  
     private $result;  

     public function __construct($Type, $Chance) {    
         $this->Client = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
         $this->Secret = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
         $this->Server = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

         if($Type == 'auto') {    
                 $hash  = hash('sha512', $this->Client . $this->Secret . $this->Server);
                 $Result = round(hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)) / 42949672.95, 2);

                     if($Result < $Chance) {
                         $this->result = true;
                     } else {
                         $this->result = false;                      
                     }
         }
     }

     /**
     * @return boolean
     */
     public function isReturnLessThanChance() { return $this->result; }
 }

$bet = new Bet("", "");
if ($bet->isResultLessThanChance()) {
    return 1;
else
    return 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much I manage to get that code working. I'm assuming you meant isReturnLessThanChance for both? Or are they suppose to be different functions?

Comment: In new php code you should name constructor `__construct`, not `Bet`

Answer (score -1):

you can try this also.

```
if($Bet === true) { return "1"; } else { return "2"; }
```

`===` check data type as well as value. then `(true !== 1)`.